# ElasticSearch: Cluster-to-Cluster replication using polling

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, database-replication

I have two DCs (A and P), each of them runs its own ES cluster in Active/Passive deployment,
I would like to mirror all data from A to P continuously with latency as low as possible (up to 60 sec).
I try to avoid using another DB (such as CouchBase) as a primary DB due to the additional computing resources and complexity involved.

I can go ahead using the snapshot and restore mechanism (see https://discuss.elastic.co/t/continuous-async-replication/17088/2) , but I fear that P will not get updated soon enough.
I thought of writing a custom poller for changes that polls A for changes (for example, based on last poll time-stamp) and apply them to P (as suggested by Shay here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/replication-strategies/3081).

Is that a viable option? Any drawbacks? Can you suggest another strategy?

Comment: Are you sure that your custom ploller complete the replication changes in less than 60 seconds? If yes, you can go for it.

Comment: It depends of-course on the volume of changes but I intend to use batching so I hope it can make it.

Comment: Why don't you perform all the operations from A to P simultaneously? Meaning, you write/update to A, you do the same, at the same time in P.

Comment: I fear that writing to both clusters will ave consistency issues. For example, If write to A succeeds and then write to B fails (e.g. version mismatch..),  I have also to rollback the change to A, which I may be not able to do so (the data may have already updated again). Or, if one cluster is offline, I have to use some kind of persistent queue  to "remember" the updates made until it comes back online.  This adds complexity.